# Mocking static method in Spring 5.0.7.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mocking

I have a Spring 5.0.7.RELEASE app, with some WebLayer tests
I have this test in my app:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class HongoControllerTest  {


    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;



    @Before
    public void setup() {

        mockStatic(TranslationUtils.class);
}
```

but when I run the test I have this error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
The used MockMaker SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker does not support the creation of static mocks

Mockito's inline mock maker supports static mocks based on the Instrumentation API.
You can simply enable this mock mode, by placing the 'mockito-inline' artifact where you are currently using 'mockito-core'.
Note that Mockito's inline mock maker is not supported on Android.
```

}

I also tried with this approach:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest( TranslationUtils.class )
@WebAppConfiguration
public class HongoControllerTest  {
...
}
```

but then I have the error in the console:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Extension API internal error: org.powermock.api.extension.proxyframework.ProxyFrameworkImpl could not be located in classpath.

    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.registerProxyframework(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:146)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.chunkClass(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:181)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:96)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:89)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:49)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.<init>(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:32)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.<init>(PowerMockRunner.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBu
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue in a Spring Boot application.

```
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>2.5.6</version>
```

I did add the following dependency in the pom.xml as they said in the logs and it worked:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
  <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```